# limit data within an over statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, over-clause

I want to Aggregate a column over timestamps.

Here an example:

Table contains columns like col1, col2, ..., col_ts (timestamp column).

```
SELECT
SUM(col1) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) SUM1,
SUM(col2) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) SUM2
FROM ...
```

Now i want only the 2 PRECEDING and the 2 FOLLOWING ROWS SUMMED when the difference between the timestamps are <= 5 minutes.

For example, lets look at these timestamp values:

```
14.09.15 15:44:00
14.09.15 15:50:00
14.09.15 15:51:00
14.09.15 15:52:00
14.09.15 15:53:00
```

When were are at the row with the timestamp value "14.09.15 15:51:00", i want the SUM OVER the values from 15:50 until 15:53, because the difference between 15:50 and 15:44 is bigger than 5 minutes.

Is there a way to write such a condition in the over clause?

Or is there anyone with a good and performant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i see the problem here. thanks florin. so what about some preprocessing? i could find a solution, but i am not sure if there is a faster solution:

```
select col_ts, 
       n, 
       SUM(n) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ROWS BETWEEN LEFT_VALUE PRECEDING AND RIGHT_VALUE FOLLOWING) MY_SUM,
       SUM(n) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts RANGE BETWEEN interval '5' second PRECEDING AND interval '5' second FOLLOWING) OLD_SUM
from (
       select col_ts,
              n,
              CASE
              WHEN (LEAD(col_ts,1) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ) - col_ts) <= INTERVAL '5' second 
              THEN 
                   CASE
                   WHEN (LEAD(col_ts,2) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ) - LEAD(col_ts,1) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts )) <= INTERVAL '5' second 
                   THEN 2 
                   ELSE 1
                   END
             ELSE 0
             END AS RIGHT_VALUE,
             CASE 
             WHEN (col_ts - LAG(col_ts,1) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ) ) <= INTERVAL '5' second 
             THEN 
                  CASE 
                  WHEN (LAG(col_ts,1) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ) - LAG(col_ts,2) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts )) <= INTERVAL '5' second 
                  THEN 2 
                  ELSE 1
                  END
            ELSE 0
            END AS LEFT_VALUE
      from fg_test
  );
```

Result:

```
COL_TS                           N   MY_SUM      OLD_SUM
---------------------------  -----  -------  -----------
15.09.15 09:34:24,069000000      1        6            6
15.09.15 09:34:28,000000000      2       10           15
15.09.15 09:34:29,000000000      3       15           15
15.09.15 09:34:30,000000000      4       14           14
15.09.15 09:34:31,000000000      5       12           14
15.09.15 09:34:37,000000000      6        6            6
```

what do you think?

Comment: wow, that's cool! I think this is an answer! About performance you should check yourself. The ideea is to limit/filter the rows on which you are calculating lead/lag. Smaller -> faster. I'll vote your answer, it is cool.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too much for sql. You can restrict the number or elements in window, you can restrict somehow(see bellow) the values, but not both at the same time.

```
drop table fg_test;
create table fg_test(col_ts timestamp, n number);

insert into fg_test values (systimestamp, 1);
insert into fg_test values (systimestamp+4/1440/60, 2);
insert into fg_test values (systimestamp+5/1440/60, 3);
insert into fg_test values (systimestamp+6/1440/60, 4);
insert into fg_test values (systimestamp+7/1440/60, 5);
insert into fg_test values (systimestamp+13/1440/60, 6);

select col_ts, n, 
  SUM(n) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) SUM1,
  SUM(n) OVER (ORDER BY col_ts RANGE BETWEEN current row AND interval '5' second FOLLOWING) SUMNEW
from fg_test;
```

Results:

```
COL_TS                                   N       SUM1       SUM2
------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
14-SEP-15 06.16.28.825395000 PM          1          3          3 
14-SEP-15 06.16.33.000000000 PM          2          6         14 
14-SEP-15 06.16.34.000000000 PM          3          9         12 
14-SEP-15 06.16.35.000000000 PM          4         12          9 
14-SEP-15 06.16.36.000000000 PM          5         15          5 
14-SEP-15 06.16.42.000000000 PM          6         11          6
```

(sorry for not taking the exact example as in your question)

The alternative is to write some PL/SQL(open a cursor and do some processing).