# Oracle window function with dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample data is as follows:

```
date       value  
2015-09-09      1  
2015-09-08      2  
2015-09-07      3  
2015-09-04      4  
2015-09-03      5
```

I need to calculate sum value for each date and two days before, so the result should appear:

```
2015-09-09      6 --sum value of 2015-09-09, 2015-09-08, 2015-09-07  
2015-09-08      5 --sum value of 2015-09-08, 2015-09-07  
2015-09-07      3 --sum value of 2015-09-07  
2015-09-04      9 --sum value of 2015-09-04, 2015-09-03  
2015-09-03      5 --sum value of 2015-09-03
```

How could I achieve it with window functions in Oracle?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Nothing... Many attempts with no satisfied result. :(

Comment: Use an analytic function, with a window clause that defines a logical range based on an interval: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97640

Comment: very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32566575/319875)

Comment: You said you've done `Nothing...` and then go on to say `Many attempts`.  That means you ***do*** have code.  We don't need to see code that works, if it already worked you wouldn't have a question.  We benefit from seeing what you're *tried*.  You should include in your post the attempts you have made, including error messages and/or in what way the results were not what you desired.

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is sparse you should use the RANGE clause:

```
SELECT OrderDay, 
SUM(quantity) OVER 
(ORDER BY OrderDay RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS totals,
Quantity
FROM Order
```

or even shorter using the default window:

```
SELECT OrderDay, 
SUM(quantity) OVER 
(ORDER BY OrderDay RANGE INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING) AS totals,
Quantity
FROM Order
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an *Order* table with *OrderDay* as a Date field and *Quantity* as number of orders in that day. Now have to order by day and use [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97640) to sum only current date and two days before.

The key is to use `RANGE BETWEEN` clause that operates over a window that includes the current and two prior days. Here is a solution:

```
SELECT 
SUM(Quantity) OVER 
(ORDER BY OrderDay RANGE BETWEEN
            INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING
            AND
            CURRENT ROW ) totals,
Quantity
FROM Order
```

Comment: No, if you try to execute your query you will see in days [07,08,09] result is [12,9,6], but Amis result dataset for this days is [3,5,6].

Comment: Needs to be RANGE not ROWS, and use a logical preceding clause